# Multiple cypher MATCH queries to get row count

Tags: cypher

I am trying to get the row count for each node. 
I am using the following cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Product) WHERE p.modifiedDTS > 10 
RETURN {productCount: count(p)};
```

How can I use this with multiple unrelated matches?

```
MATCH (p:Product)
MATCH (i:Item)
WHERE p.modifiedDTS > 10
RETURN {productCount: count(p) ,itemCount: count(i)}
```

This returns 0 as the result, but should return 1 for the productCount.

Found one solution, but there are probably better options out there.

```
MATCH(p:Product) where p.modifiedDTS > 10 
Return count(p) as count, "product" as node
UNION ALL
MATCH(i:Item) where i.modifiedDTS > 10
Return count(i) as count, "item" as node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OPTIONAL MATCH` that way the where only works on the previous optional match and doesn't throw out other rows.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE p.modifiedDTS > 10
OPTIONAL MATCH (i:Item)
WHERE i.modifiedDTS > 10
RETURN {productCount: count(p) ,itemCount: count(i)}
```